# Displaying Clickable Grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, checkbox

What's the best way to display a grid like below which will allow the user to select multiple boxes and then have the page capture the selected elements?

The existing code I am working with seems inadequate since it displays a grid of buttons where only one can be selected:

```html
<tr>
<th>6-8 AM</th>
<td><button type="button" class="btn"></button></td>
<td><button type="button" class="btn"></button></td>
<td><button type="button" class="btn"></button></td>
<td><button type="button" class="btn"></button></td> 
<td><button type="button" class="btn"></button></td>     
<td><button type="button" class="btn"></button></td>  
<td><button type="button" class="btn"></button></td>                                   
</tr>
```

[image]

Comment: there is no problem in creating this kind of design right!! you are just asking an approach to select multiple boxes there!!

Comment: What is your question ? How to design that or how to make it clickable and submit it ?

Comment: What would be your first idea? Have you tried anything?

Comment: I recommend you to improve this question by showing which ideas you have in mind, so that we can help you improve it, or confirm that your idea is a good one. But, as it is right now, this question has too many answers. Perhaps it will be closed for beeing too broad.

Comment: I mean... if I were you I would create first some DIV or rather table elements and used google to see how to use the click event. Have you?

Answer (score 2):

write a function to capture onclick and store it against a variable of to data of an element and then send it to server when user wants to synchronize

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with for loops. First, you would want to declare some variables

```
var table = document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0];
var days = ["M", "T", "W", "TH", "F", "S", "SU"];
var times = ["6-8AM", "8-10AM", "10-12PM", "12-1PM", "1-3PM", 
             "3-5PM", "5-7PM", "7-9PM", "9-11PM"];
var headerRow = document.createElement("tr");
table.appendChild(headerRow);
var emptyCell = document.createElement("th");
emptyCell.innerHTML = '';
headerRow.appendChild(emptyCell);
```

You would first work on creating the header row with the names of the dates. The best approach for this is to iterate over the `days` array we just created. However, because arrays are zero-indexed, we must specify the index as `day - 1`.

```
for (var day = 1; day <= days.length; day++) {
    var th = document.createElement("th");
    th.innerHTML = days[day - 1];
    headerRow.appendChild(th);
}
```

You then want to create 10 rows for the number of time slots available. The first-child of each of these rows will be the time slot.

```
for (var time = 1; time <= times.length; time++) {
    var tr = document.createElement("tr");
    var td = document.createElement("td");
    td.innerHTML = times[time - 1];
    table.appendChild(tr);
    tr.appendChild(td);
}
```

This is an n x n table, so you would use a nested for loop. First you would iterate over all the time slots, in other words all the rows. Then you would iterate over all of the days, in other words the columns.

```
for (var time = 1; time <= times.length; time++) {
    var tr = document.querySelector("tr")[i];
    table.appendChild(tr);
    for (var day = 1; day <= days.length; day++) {
        var td = document.createElement("td");
        td.innerHTML = "<input type='checkbox' />"
        tr.appendChild(td);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using classes to know which cells are selected,
this also makes the styling very straight-forward and interactive.

I would recommend creating the table programmatically using 2 nested loops like @Suresh Reddy Guntaka recommended.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    td {
      padding: 5%;
    }

    .unselected_cell {
      background-color: #EED;
    }

    .selected_cell {
      background-color: green;
    }
  </style>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
</head>
<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Time</th>
      <th>M</th>
      <th>T</th>
      <th>W</th>
      <th>Tu</th>
      <th>F</th>
      <th>S</th>
      <th>Su</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>6-8AM</td>
      <td id=M_6-8 class="unselected_cell" onclick="handleCellClick(this);" />
      <td id=T_6-8 class="unselected_cell" onclick="handleCellClick(this);" />
      <td id=W_6-8 class="unselected_cell" onclick="handleCellClick(this);" />
      <td id=Tu_6-8 class="unselected_cell" onclick="handleCellClick(this);" />
      <td id=F_6-8 class="unselected_cell" onclick="handleCellClick(this);" />
      <td id=S_6-8 class="unselected_cell" onclick="handleCellClick(this);" />
      <td id=Su_6-8 class="unselected_cell" onclick="handleCellClick(this);" />
    <tr>
      <td>8-10AM</td>
      <td id=M_8-10 class="unselected_cell" onclick="handleCellClick(this);"/>
      <td id=T_8-10 class="unselected_cell" onclick="handleCellClick(this);" />
      <td id=W_8-10 class="unselected_cell" onclick="handleCellClick(this);" />
      <td id=Tu_8-10 class="unselected_cell" onclick="handleCellClick(this);" />
      <td id=F_8-10 class="unselected_cell" onclick="handleCellClick(this);" />
      <td id=S_8-10 class="unselected_cell" onclick="handleCellClick(this);" />
      <td id=Su_8-10 class="unselected_cell" onclick="handleCellClick(this);" />
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>10-12PM</td>
      <td id=M_10-12 class="unselected_cell" onclick="handleCellClick(this);" />
      <td id=T_10-12 class="unselected_cell" onclick="handleCellClick(this);" />
      <td id=W_10-12 class="unselected_cell" onclick="handleCellClick(this);" />
      <td id=Tu_10-12 class="unselected_cell" onclick="handleCellClick(this);" />
      <td id=F_10-12 class="unselected_cell" onclick="handleCellClick(this);" />
      <td id=S_10-12 class="unselected_cell" onclick="handleCellClick(this);" />
      <td id=Su_10-12 class="unselected_cell" onclick="handleCellClick(this);" />
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>12-14PM</td>
      <td id=M_12-14 class="unselected_cell" onclick="handleCellClick(this);" />
      <td id=T_12-14 class="unselected_cell" onclick="handleCellClick(this);" />
      <td id=W_12-14 class="unselected_cell" onclick="handleCellClick(this);" />
      <td id=Tu_12-14 class="unselected_cell" onclick="handleCellClick(this);" />
      <td id=F_12-14 class="unselected_cell" onclick="handleCellClick(this);" />
      <td id=S_12-14 class="unselected_cell" onclick="handleCellClick(this);" />
      <td id=Su_12-14 class="unselected_cell" onclick="handleCellClick(this);" />
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>12-14PMM</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>14-16PM</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>16-18PM</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>18-20PM</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>20-22PM</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>22-00AM</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>00-02AM</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>02-04AM</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>04-06AM</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

    <button onclick="handleButtonClick()">FINISHED</button>

 <script>
   function handleCellClick(cell) {
     if(cell.className.indexOf("unselected_cell") > -1) {
       cell.className = cell.className.replace("unselected_cell", "selected_cell");
     } else {
       cell.className = cell.className.replace("selected_cell", "unselected_cell");
     }
   }

   function handleButtonClick() {
     $(".selected_cell").each(function(index) {
       console.log($(this).prop('id'));
     });
   }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are still interested, here is my more JQuery driven solution to what you are trying to do. It uses AJAX to send the schedule back to the server to be acted on.

```
          <style>
                th {background-color: silver; 
                    width: 70px;
                }
                .slot {
                    background-color:gray;
                }
                .selslot {
                    background-color: blue !important;
                }
            </style>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                var days = ["M", "T", "W", "TH", "F", "S", "SU"];
                var times = ["6-8AM", "8-10AM", "10-12PM", "12-1PM", "1-3PM",
                             "3-5PM", "5-7PM", "7-9PM", "9-11PM"];
                $(document).ready(function () {

                    var $table = $("#tblSch");

                    var $headerRow = $("<tr><td></td></tr>");
                    for (i = 0; i < days.length; ++i) {
                        $headerRow.append("<th>" + days[i] + "</th>");
                    }

                    var $head = $("<thead/>");
                    $head.append($headerRow);
                    $table.append($head);
                    $tbody = $("<tbody/>");
                    for (var j = 0; j < times.length; ++j) {
                        var $row = $("<tr><th>" + times[j] + "</th></tr>");
                        for (var k = 0; k < 7; ++k) {
                            $row.append("<td class='slot'></td>")
                        }
                        $tbody.append($row);
                    }
                    $table.append($tbody);
                    $(".slot").click(function (evtObj) {
                        if ($(evtObj.target).hasClass("selslot")) { $(evtObj.target).removeClass("selslot") }
                        else { $(evtObj.target).addClass("selslot") }
                    });

                    $("button").click(function () {
                        var $selected = $(".selslot");
                        var timeSlots = [];
                        $selected.each(function () {
                            var cx = this.cellIndex;
                            var rx = this.parentNode.rowIndex;
                            var item = { day: days[cx - 1], time: times[rx - 1] };
                            timeSlots[timeSlots.length] = item;

                        })
                        saveItemList(timeSlots);

                    })
                })
                function saveItemList(list) {
                    $("#list").html("");
                    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; ++i) {
                        $("#list").append("Day:" + list[i].day + " Time: " + list[i].time + "<br />");
                    }

                    $.ajax({
                        url: "handler.asmx",
                        data: JSON.stringify(list),
                        dataType: 'json',
                        type: 'POST',
                        success: function (data) {
                            // do somethign
                        },
                        error: function (data, status, jqXHR) {
                            // do somthing
                        }
                    });
                }
            </script>
        </head>
        <body>
                <div class="container" style="margin-top:20px;">
                    <table id="tblSch"></table>
                </div>
                <button type="button">Save Schedule</button>
               <div id="list"></div>
        </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the functionality you want is really a functionality of checkboxes, which retain a yes/no user selection and can be passed on form submit.  Just because you need checkbox functionality, doesn't mean it has to look like a checkbox, though.

Codepen with a basic example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RrQELP

```css
      td {border:1px solid;padding:3px;}
      td input[type="checkbox"] {position:absolute;
        left:-9999px;}
      td label {background-color:#333; padding:8px;display:block;color:#fff;border-radius:3px;font-family:arial;}
      td input:checked + label {background-color:#669900}
```

```html
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <input type="checkbox" id="item1"/>
            <label for="item1">Label</label>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="checkbox" id="item2"/>
            <label for="item2">Label</label>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="checkbox" id="item3"/>
            <label for="item3">Label</label>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="checkbox" id="item4"/>
            <label for="item4">Label</label>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="checkbox" id="item5"/>
            <label for="item5">Label</label>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <input type="checkbox" id="item6"/>
            <label for="item6">Label</label>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="checkbox" id="item7"/>
            <label for="item7">Label</label>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="checkbox" id="item8"/>
            <label for="item8">Label</label>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="checkbox" id="item9"/>
            <label for="item9">Label</label>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="checkbox" id="item10"/>
            <label for="item10">Label</label>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
```

You can certainly do a bunch of JS magic (and there are some clever examples already given!), but sometimes starting with the semantic element and creatively styling it will get you further faster - and with a lot less effort.